# why E-5 and A-open doesn't sound same even when they have same 110 frequency?

Tags: guitar, theory

I am trying to play Brushy one string's "No man stop me"

on a different set of notes. He uses 3 notes there E-5, E-3 E-1.

E-5 and A-open have same 110 frequency. But I am not able to switch E-5 with A-open and have the same sound.

When playing the same note, how can I duplicate the same sound on different strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental frequency of a note only affects the *pitch* we hear, not the *timbre*.

Timbre is the quality of a note that makes it possible to tell what instrument is playing the note. Imagine if a bassoon or cello were playing the same A at 110 Hz fundamental frequency. It would be the same note, but you would instantly be able to tell that it's a cello or a bassoon and not a guitar.

Obviously the difference between a fretted A and open A on the same guitar is much more subtle than the difference between different instruments. There are many subtle differences between open and fretted A. The sounding lengths, string diameter and stiffness, string tension, and finally the difference between the impedance at the nut versus the finger and fret.

Being able to tell the difference between the same note fretted versus open is a sign of a fairly developed ear, so while you might be a little frustrated at having trouble reproducing the exact right sound, you can also feel happy that you're able to tell the difference.

Comment: Did you mean impedance? Possibly 'tone' would work?

Comment: @Tim I meant impedance, as in mechanical impedance, which has an effect on to what extent different vibration modes are reflected back down along the string.